Dickey-Fuller test statistical significance
I recently read about the Dickey-Fuller test.
Firstly about the transformation from
$$
y_t=\rho y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t
$$
to:
$$
y_t-y_{t-1}=(\rho-1) y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t
$$
I assumed it is to get the statistic of $\delta=\rho -1$
which is a pivotal parameter not dependant on some unknown statistic? or am i mistaken?
Secondly, as I understood the statistical test made on delta is one-sided. why do we omit negative values whose absolute value of rho is larger than 1?

First, the distribution is not easier, but we can take the default t-statistic reported by regression packages.
Second, we "omit" positive values of $\delta$ where $\rho$ is larger than one because these correspond to explosive processes which are typically viewed as implausible in applications. See Explosive processes, non-stationarity and unit roots, how to distinguish?, though.

As to my knowledge in statistics we try to asses pivot parameters because they don't depend on the unknown quantity in question.I actually meant that delta is a pivotal parameter while rho is not? Or am i completely mistaken ?

A pivot is a quantity whose distribution does not depend on the parameter(s), e.g. $(X-\mu)/\sigma$ for a normal random variable would be a pivot. Both $\delta$ and $\rho$ are parameters, so that indeed has nothing to do with pivotalness, I would say.

Ok ,thank you very much ! Ill try to look up the original paper to understand this transformation
